# Automatic tap the button of iPhone simulator app

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to develop a frame work in which I want to launch automatic simulator as well as i am trying to launch the app on simulator and i am also want to tap the any button of that app

Comment: This question actually belongs on Stack Overflow and will likely be moved there soon. Hopefully my answer will help you nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The UIAutomation suite that comes with the SDK can perform taps (and just about everything else) on the simulator. This article from O'Reilly does a good job of explaining the basics:

[**How to use UIAutomation to create iPhone UI tests**](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1646-how-to-use-uiautomation-to-create-iphone-ui-tests/)